# Output 1 array from 2 different multidimensional arrays in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need a little help with multidimensional arrays. I need to output/create an new array from two other arrays in PHP. I know that my example is wrong, but here is an example of what I have that almost works:

```
 $myarray = array(
      'customid1' = array(
                  name=> 'Tim',
                  address=> '23 Some Address'
                  ),
      'customid2' = array(
                  name=> 'John',
                  address=> 'Another Address'
                  )
 );

 $keys = array();
 $values = array(); 

 foreach($myarray as $key => $keyitem) {
        $getkeys = $myarray[$key]['name'] .'-and-a-string';
        $keys[] = $getkeys;
 } 

 foreach($myarray as $value => $valueitem) {
        $getvalues = 'some-other-text-'. $myarray[$key]['address'];
        $values[] = $getvalues;           
    }

 $newarray = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

The code above will get all the keys right, except the values for that key inside the new array. Instead it shows the last value in the array in all of keys. So my print_r results will look like:

```
Array ( Tim-and-a-string => some-other-text-Another Address 
        John-and-a-string => some-other-text-Another Address 
)
```

As you can see, 'some-other-text-Another Address' appears on all of them, but the second key  'Tim-and-a-string' needs to have 'some-other-text-23 Some Address' included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very minor error but you are using the wrong variable:

You are using `$key` instead of `$value` in the second `foreach()`.

`$key` would be the same as the last key in the loop before since the new foreach loop does not override it.

This should work:

```
$myarray = array(
      'customid1' = array(
                  name=> 'Tim',
                  address=> '23 Some Address'
                  ),
      'customid2' = array(
                  name=> 'John',
                  address=> 'Another Address'
                  )
 );

 $keys = array();
 $values = array(); 

 foreach($myarray as $key => $keyitem) {
        $getkeys = $myarray[$key]['name'] .'-and-a-string';
        $keys[] = $getkeys;
 } 

 foreach($myarray as $value => $valueitem) {
        $getvalues = 'some-other-text-'. $myarray[$value]['address'];
        $values[] = $getvalues;           
    }

 $newarray = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$newarray = array_combine(
    array_values(array_map(function ($v) { return $v['name'].'-and-a-string'; }, $myarray)),
    array_values(array_map(function ($v) { return 'some-other-text-'.$v['address']; }, $myarray))
);
```